# optimization a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is an expression

```
const reg = new RegExp(`^([\u4e00-\u9fa5a-zA-Z0-9_-]){1,${num}}$`)
```

Which design to detect a wold's length less than `num`, but it able to stuck the browser when the num is large than 500+. How can I optimize it?

Comment: The alternation `[\u4e00-\u9fa5a-zA-Z0-9_-]|.` is just equal to `.` as it will always be matched if the first part doesn't. The whole thing simplifies to just `^.{1,${num}}$` which in turn is the same as checking `str.length >= 1 && str.length <= num` without using a regex.

Comment: @VLAZ Thanks very much. It resolves my problem, and I still need a solution for common. I have fixed the expression to remove the `|.`

Comment: If you don't need to extract any captured data but just validate, then you can remove the capturing group (the `(` and `)`) - it's making the regex engine do a lot more work and if you're not using it, it's irrelevant. So, perhaps `^[\u4e00-\u9fa5a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,${num}}$` is all you need if you're doing `reg.test(string)`.